# Is it possible for one of $(\phi\wedge\psi)\wedge\theta$ and $\phi\wedge(\psi\wedge\theta)$ to be true and the other false?

Tags: logic, proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm taking 'Introduction to Mathematical Thinking' and is asked :

Is it possible for one of $(\phi\wedge\psi)\wedge\theta$ and $\phi\wedge(\psi\wedge\theta)$ to be true and the other false ? (If not then the associative property holds for conjunction) Reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property the associative property for conjunction holds :

[image]

Here is my solution :

Conjunction is true of both conjunctions are true.
$$\begin{array} {|c|}
\hline
\phi & \psi & \theta & \phi\wedge\psi & (\phi\wedge\psi)\wedge\theta & \phi\wedge(\psi\wedge\theta) &  && \\ \hline
T& T& T& T& T& T& \\ \hline
T& F& T& F& F& F& \\ \hline
T& T& F& T& F& T& \\ \hline
T& T& F& T& F& T& \\ \hline
T& F& F& F& F& F& \\ \hline
F& F& T& F& F& F& \\ \hline
F& T& F& F& F& F& \\ \hline
F& F& F& F& F& F& \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

From this truth $(\phi\wedge\psi)\wedge\theta$ $\nrightarrow$ $\phi\wedge(\psi\wedge\theta)$ and $(\phi\wedge\psi)\wedge\theta$ $\nleftarrow$ $\phi\wedge(\psi\wedge\theta)$ so answer is yes : It is possible for one of $(\phi\wedge\psi)\wedge\theta$ and $\phi\wedge(\psi\wedge\theta)$ to be true and the other false. But I believe this to be incorrect , is there a mistake in my truth table ?

Comment: Your doubt is correct : it is **not** possible.

Comment: Wrong 3rd and 4th row of the RH column.

Comment: Wrong in 4th and 5th roe assignments of truth values to the sentential varaibles.

Comment: @blue-sky  You still haven't fixed the problems with your table as pointed out by Mauro and Paul ...

Comment: @Bram28 thanks for reminder but I'm taking this math course in my spare time and unfortunately my time is extremely limited during 'normal' working hours (GMT) . Also math at this level (albeit likely basic for most on this site) is a slow process for me to understand the valuable assistance I receive so I take extra time before posting updates. I do plan to update the question with answer and accept @@aPaulT answer tonight.

Comment: @blue-sky I totally understand!  Good luck with your studies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip 1: Make sure you include all eight rows (and don't double up) by being systematic.   (Check sum: Count the $T$ and $F$ in the first three columns of your table; you should have 4 of each in each column.)

Tip 2: If you include a column for $\phi\wedge\psi$ you may as well do so for $\psi\wedge\theta$ too.

Tip 3: $F$ and $T$ look awfully alike when in a block.   Make them pop out.

$$\def\T{\color{navy}{\mathcal T}} \def\F{\color{crimson}{\mathsf F}}
\begin{array} {|c:c:c|c:c|c:c|} \hline
\phi & \psi & \theta & \phi\wedge\psi & \psi\wedge\theta & (\phi\wedge\psi)\wedge\theta & \phi\wedge(\psi\wedge\theta)  \\ \hline
\T& \T& \T& \T& \T& \T& \T \\ \hdashline
\T& \T& \F& \T& \F& \F& \F \\ \hdashline
\T& \F& \T& \F& \F& \F& \F \\ \hdashline
\T& \F& \F& \F& \F& \F& \F \\ \hdashline
\F& \T& \T& \F& \T& \F& \F \\ \hdashline
\F& \T& \F& \F& \F& \F& \F \\ \hdashline
\F& \F& \T& \F& \F& \F& \F \\ \hdashline
\F& \F& \F& \F& \F& \F& \F \\ \hdashline
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 3):

There are a few mistakes in your truth table. The third and fourth rows have the same values for $\phi$, $\varphi$ and $\theta$ so you have missed out one combination. And some of your truth values for $\phi\wedge(\varphi\wedge\theta)$ are wrong. It might be easier to work these out if you have a column for $\varphi\wedge\theta$, as you did for $\phi\wedge\varphi$ when working out the values for the first conjunction.

Comment: thanks, I will make edits. "some of your truth values for ϕ∧(φ∧θ) are wrong." Which ones are wrong ? as truth value T for values where both ϕ and (φ∧θ)  are true. Where ϕ or (φ∧θ) is false, true value is F ?

Comment: @blue-sky That isn't what you've done. Note that there's no column in your table for $\varphi\wedge\theta$. It looks like you've used the column for $\phi\wedge\varphi$ instead, so what you've calculated is $\phi\wedge(\phi\wedge\varphi$).